# Is there a way to make Dash not update the whole layout at every user interaction?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

The way my application is built, Dash is going to reload the whole page every time a new selection is made in a dropdown or through a date slicer, for example. Depending on how many visualizations I'm willing to build, this may lead to a performance issue. Is there a way to keep Dash from updating the whole layout?

Comment: maybe `uirevision` is what you are looking for: https://community.plotly.com/t/preserving-ui-state-like-zoom-in-dcc-graph-with-uirevision-with-dash/15793

Answer (score 0):

Dash callbacks are only going to update the specific outputs they have listed, not the entire layout. Dash creates React components, and that's how React works. You haven't shared any code, but it sounds like you could be much more specific with the outputs your callbacks are changing.